# Related nodes view block based only on child Taxonomy Terms

Tags: 7, views

I have a 2-levels Taxonomy Hierarchy structured like this:

```
Parent Term
    - Child Term 1
    - Child Term 2
    - ...
```

My goal is to create a view block, where related nodes based **only** on child taxonomy terms are displayed.

How can I do that?

Thanks

EDIT
The created views block will be displayed in the node's page. 
So when in a node's page the views block should display other nodes that are related to the current viewed node based only on the child terms and not the parent.

Comment: What do nodes reference through the ER field? Parents, children, both? You can try using the Has taxonomy term Contextual with depth.

Comment: The nodes reference both Parents and Children. I have tried "Has Taxonomy term with Depth" as a contextual filter with no luck.

Comment: Perhaps query alter?

Comment: What do you mean by `related nodes based only on child taxonomy terms`? Can you add some concrete examples to your question? Something like, _"If the page is for a node with term `Parent Term`, the block should show nodes with the terms???? But, if the page is for a node with the term `Child Term 1`, the block should show nodes with the terms???"_

Comment: @runswithscissors I edited the question. Hope is understood now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it still isn't clear. Can you please, **literally** write something like this: "If the page is for a node with term Parent Term, the block should show nodes with the terms XXXXX. But, if the page is for a node with the term Child Term 1, the block should show nodes with the terms YYYYY."